# Finding the limit of $\arctan(x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ as $x$ tends to $0$ using Taylor expansions

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion

Here is my attempt to find $\lim_{x\to 0} \arctan (x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}$ (using Taylor expansions):

$\arctan (x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = e^{\ln (\arctan(x)) \frac{1}{x^2}}$

Then, using the Taylor expansion:

$(\arctan{x}) -1 =-1 + x + o(x)$

And composition with $\ln$ (recall $\ln (1 +x) =  x + o(x)$):

$\ln(\arctan (x)) = -1 + x + o(x)$

Then, $\ln(\arctan (x)) \frac{1}{x^2} = -\frac{1}{x^2} + \frac{1}{x} + o(\frac{1}{x})$

Then, using the Taylor expansion of $\exp$ (recall $e^x = 1 +x + o(x)$):

$\arctan (x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = 1+o(1)$

I am not completely sure about the last step. I feel like it is wrong. Is there another (if it is wrong) way to find this limit ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first step is fine

$$\arctan (x)^{\frac{1}{x^2}} = e^{\ln (\arctan(x)) \frac{1}{x^2}}$$

then recall that $\arctan x \to 0$ and therefore, we are implicitely assuming that $x\to 0^+$, $\ln(\arctan x) \to -\infty$, thus $\ln (\arctan(x)) \frac{1}{x^2} \to -\infty$ and $e^{\ln (\arctan(x)) \frac{1}{x^2}} \to 0$.

We really don't need Taylor expansion in this case.

Moreover this step is wrong

$$\ln(\arctan (x)) = -1 + x + o(x)$$

indeed $\arctan (x)=x + o(x)$ and then $\ln(\arctan (x)) = \ln(x + o(x))$.